# Group by Date from ISODate in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I blocked with group by date from ISODate in mongodb and finally got a solution that i like to share with you guys. Maybe this code will be helpful for someone who is searching for. I tried to search over the internet and i could not find the exact result or similar to that, so hope this helps you. Thank you.

### Difficulties which i faced technically:

1. ISODate from mongodb collection is in the type string not in date.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution for the question, mongodb query for the expected question is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSW6u.png)

Hope this query is helpful for someone i guess. Thank you.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.